# MVC Razor bootstrap Date Range validation not working properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, bootstrap-datepicker

My input control is rendered as:

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" id="elements_3__Value"
    name="elements[3].Value" type="date" value="" 
    data-val="true" data-val-required="D.O.B is Required." 
    data-val-range="D.O.B can only be between 1/01/2017 and 2/01/2017." 
    data-val-range-min="1/01/2017" data-val-range-max="2/01/2017">
```

The scripts that are loaded on the page are:

```
jquery-1.10.2.js
bootstrap.js
bootstrap-datepicker.js
respond.js
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
```

Date range & date selected in textbox are in `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

Now my selected date is "01/12/2017" i.e. 12 Jan 2017 but still validation shows me error as:

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi @Anand. Appreciate this is an old post but did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same issue.